# how to change Icon color when icon is onpressed in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make like systems in my app.

I wanna make when I clicked item that heart Icon color will be changed.

I was tried using state array, when I hit Item, array element changing is work.

But, I couldn't change Icon color

I checked the console, when render page all Icon index is loded

here is my code

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

  const [likedMusics, setMusics] = useState([]);

 const handleLike = (musicId, index) => {
    if (!likedMusics.includes(index)) {
      likedMusics.push(index);
      axios
        .post(`${PREFIX_URL}/music/${musicId}/like`)
        .then(res => alert(res.data.message))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    } else {
      likedMusics.splice(likedMusics.indexOf(index), 1);
      axios
        .delete(`${PREFIX_URL}/music/${musicId}/like`)
        .then(res => alert(res.data.message))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  };

  const likedStyle = idx => {
    console.log(idx, 'chekd1!!!!!');

    if (likedMusics.indexOf(idx) > -1) {
      console.log(idx, '@@@@@@@!!!!!');
      return 'white';
    } else {
      return 'pink';
    }
  };

...
....
return (
    <FlatList
      data={props.comments}
      keyExtractor={item => item.music.createdAt}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              <Icon
                name="heart-outline"
                color={likedStyle(index)}
                size={30}
                style={styles.icon}
                onPress={() => {
                  handleLike(item.music.id, index);
                  console.log(likedMusics);
                }}
              ></Icon>
        </View>
      )}
    ></FlatList>
...
```

what I got in console when the pages was rendered
: 
0 chekd1!!!!!
1 chekd1!!!!!
2 chekd1!!!!!
3 chekd1!!!!!
4 chekd1!!!!!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create an Icon component inside `TouchableOpacity`, and with its `onPress` you switch your color
Edit -> Switch Icon `View` to `TouchableOpacity`